# two runners run a race with approximately normal distribution, what percentage of the time will one runner beat the other by at least .2 seconds

Tags: normal-distribution

Johnnie runs a race with mean M1 and standard deviation S1
Fred runs a the same race with mean M2 and standard deviation S2
Both runners' times are approximately normally distributed. 
How do I determine the probability that Johnnie's time will be at least x seconds faster than Freds?

Comment: Feel free to use whatever means and standard deviations you like.   I am just trying to see how one would approach the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Let us define two random variables, $J$ and $F$, which are the race times for each runner, respectively.

$$J\sim N(\mu_{J},\sigma_{J}^{2})\quad\quad F\sim N(\mu_{F},\sigma_{F}^{2})$$

We need to define the following random variable $X=(F-J)$, which represents the difference in times of the two competitors.

If we assume that $F$ and $J$ are independent, we know:

$$X\sim N\big((\mu_{F}-\mu_{J}),(\sigma_{F}^{2}+\sigma_{J}^{2})\big)$$

We want the probability that $X=(F-J)\geq x$, where $x$ is the desired difference in race times.

$$\begin{align}
\text{Pr}(X\geq x)&=1-\text{Pr}(X<x)\\
&=1-\Phi(y)
\end{align}$$

where
$$y=\frac{x-(\mu_{F}-\mu_{J})}{\sqrt{\big(\sigma_{F}^{2}+\sigma_{J}^{2}\big)}}$$

and $\Phi(\cdot)$ is the cumulative distribution function of the standard normal.

So let's imagine we have:

$$J\sim N(10.8,1.2)\quad\quad F\sim N(13.0,1.8)$$

This would tell us that:

$$X\sim N(2.2,3)$$

Say we want to determine the probability that $J$ runs faster than $F$ by at least 0.5 seconds, or $x=0.5$. The probability would be:

$$y=\frac{0.5-2.2}{\sqrt{3}}=-0.9815$$

$$\begin{align}
\text{Pr}(X\geq 0.5)&=1-\text{Pr}(X<0.5)\\
&=1-\Phi(-0.9815)\\
&=0.8368
\end{align}$$

Thus, there is an 83.68% chance that $J$ will run at least 0.5 seconds faster than $F$.

Alternatively, there is a 89.80% chance $J$ will run faster than $F$.

Comment: Please consult the wiki for the [tag:self-study] tag and follow its guidelines.

Answer (score -1):

You want a one sided Hypothesis test where the Null hypothesis says $\mu$ > $\mu_0$ where  $\mu$ = M1 and $\mu_0$ = M2+x.

If $\alpha $ is the significance level, then you would have an $\alpha $% chance of the mean M1 being less than the mean M2.

Comment: Both means are given - there's no question of hypothesis testing.

Comment: @Scortchi Notwithstanding StatsPlease's answer, do you think that my approach is invalid?  Or do you think that  StatsPlease's answer yields more tangible results?

Comment: It's not a matter of comparing different approaches: you seem to have misunderstood the question; which doesn't concern inference about unknown means from data, but is a straightforward probability calculation.

Comment: Are you saying that since the means are known, it is not meaningful to make inferences about the populations?

Comment: That's right - the population means & std deviations are known & there's no data from which to make inferences in any case.